# Permissions needed for dbms_metadata.get_ddl in a function

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, permissions, functions

> Oracle Enterprise 11.2.0.3

I'm receiving:

```
ORA-31603: object "string of type "string" not found in schema "string"
```

when executing a function that calls dbms_metadata.get_ddl.

I know that procedures/functions need have to have the permissions granted explicitly instead of through a role: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1065832643319

I also know that the permissions needed to execute dbms_metadata.get_ddl is in the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role: https://sshailesh.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/dbms_metadata-get_ddl-avoid-ora-31603-error-by-using-select_catalog_role/

However, the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE role contains over 2400 permissions.  So, what are the explicit permissions needed to execute dbms_metadata.get_ddl so that I can call it from a function?

Test Case:

```
create or replace function getddl (p_type varchar2, p_object varchar2, p_owner varchar2)
return varchar2 as
begin
  return dbms_metadata.get_ddl(p_type, p_object, p_owner);
end getddl;

create table utilities.mytable (mycol varchar2(1));

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'MYTABLE', 'UTILITIES') from dual;
<DDL>

select getddl('TABLE', 'MYTABLE', 'UTILITIES') from dual;
ORA-31603: object "MYTABLE" of type TABLE not found in schema "UTILITIES"
```

*EDIT*

So far, I have explicitly granted the following to the user that is owns getddl():

```
select any table
select any dictionary
```

Comment: Please check https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66868, especially part about invokers rights part.

Comment: @Raj Appreciate it.  I didn't consider that... and didn't find it in my research.  Based on your comment, I added the answer, but if you want to add your own answer, please do so, so that I can give you the points for it (and i'll delete my answer if you do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Raj's comment, the following works:

```
create or replace function utilities.getddl (p_type varchar2, p_object varchar2, p_owner varchar2)
authid current_user
return varchar2 as
begin
  return dbms_metadata.get_ddl(p_type, p_object, p_owner);
end getddl;

select getddl('TABLE', 'MYTABLE', 'UTILITIES') from dual;
<DDL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66868, especially part about invokers rights (added as an answer).

Comment: Please extract the relevant details from the link, and retain the link for further reading/give weight to your extract.